# Why does using a file descriptor of the family AF_UNIX cause accept() to give an "invalid argument" error?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

This is giving me an invalid argument error:

```
int listenfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
*clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLen);
```

while this does not

```
int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
*clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLen);
```

But I need it to be `AF_UNIX`. Whats the deal? I have checked the errors everywhere as well. The output of `socket()` is fine in either case, it is just during the `accept`.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
// forward declarations
int error_msg( char * msg );
int usage( char name[] );

// a function to be executed by each thread
void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg );

// globals
FILE * log_fd; // opened by main() but accessible by each thread
typedef struct sockaddr SA;

int error_msg( char * msg )
{
    printf( "%s\n", msg );
    return -1;
}

void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg ) //Thread Routine
{
    // loops to receive messages from a client;
    // when the connection is closed by the client,
    // close the socket
    int clientfd = *((int *)arg);
    char buffer[1500];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1500);
    int currentPos = 0;
    int bytesRec;
    int recvng = 1;

    while(recvng){
        bytesRec = recv(clientfd, buffer, 1500-currentPos, 0);
        currentPos += bytesRec;
        if(buffer[currentPos - 1] == '\n')
            recvng = 0;
    }

    fprintf(log_fd, "LOGGER %d %s", clientfd, buffer);
    close(clientfd);
    return NULL;
}

int usage( char name[] )
{
    printf( "Usage:\n" );
    printf( "\t%s <log-file-name> <UDS path>\n", name );
    return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
        return usage( argv[0] );

    log_fd = fopen(argv[1], "a");

    // create a server socket
    // domain (i.e., family) is AF_UNIX
    // type is SOCK_STREAM

    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    struct sockaddr_un clientAddr;
    clientAddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(clientAddr.sun_path, argv[2]);

    pthread_t tid;

    int listenfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);     

    // unlink the UDS path)
    unlink(argv[2]);

    // bind the server socket
    bind(listenfd, (SA *)&clientAddr, clientLength);    

    // listen
    listen(listenfd, 1024);
    // loop to wait for connections;
    // as each connection is accepted,
    // launch a new thread that calls
    // recv_log_msgs(), which receives
    // messages and writes them to the log file
    while(1){
        printf( "Waiting for a connection on UDS path %s...\n", argv[2] );
        int * clientfdp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *clientfdp = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &clientAddr, &clientLength);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, clientfdp);
        printf("%d",errno);
        return 0;
    }

    // when the loop ends, close the listening socket
    close(listenfd);        

    // close the log file
    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `clientAddr`? How is it initialized? What is `clientLen`? And how it is initialized? What is `SA`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know that none of those are the issue. If I change `listenfd` as shown above then everything is fine. But I'll update the post anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've edited the post to include all code, but yes I change clientAddr as well, as seen in the edit. I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Unfortunately you havn't checked for errors everywhere as you claim. Please add checks that bind() and listen() succeeds. If they fail, your accept() call will fail just as you describe.

Comment: Are you sure the file you use in the address for the `bind` call doesn't exist? Do you have permissions to create the file? To read from it? To write to it? Is the path valid?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, the file does not exist. And i just checked, `bind` is indeed giving me a "no such file or directory" error. I do have permissions. I thought the UDS path wasn't supposed to exist until `bind` is called

Comment: `bind` only tries to create the socket-file in the file-system, it doesn't create any directories in the path. For example `/tmp/socketfile` is (usually) a valid path, but `/tmp/some/direcory/socketfile` is not if `/tmp/some/directory` doesn't exist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I had it located at `/home/this/path/already/existed/socketfile', so that should have been fine, but I just changed it to 'socketfile' and it is blocking at accept now. The rest of the program still doesn't work though lol. Nothing is ever written to the log file

Comment: the code block beginning with `while(recvng){` has a couple of problems: 1) what happens when a full 1500 bytes are received?  what happens when the call to `read()` returns a error indication?  what happens when none of the read characters ends with a '\n'?

Comment: the 'usage' output is about an error, so should be routed to stderr, not stdout.  Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, ... )`

Comment: *Here is the code in its entirety*   Really?  the posted code does not compile.   It is missing the appropriate #include statements for the header files.  Are we expected to guess as to which header files were included?

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code fails to check the returned value from `malloc()`, `accept()`, and `pthread_create()` to assure those operations were successful.

Comment: in the `main()` function, why use the `while(1)` statement when the loop always exits after the first pass?   The lines of code after the `while(1)` loop will never be executed as they are not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

the main() function fails to call `pthread_join()` after calling `pthread_create()`

The result is the process exits before the thread has a chance to write anything to the log file.